# Glacier retrieval of purged files

Tags: backup, amazon-web-services, amazon-glacier, cloudberry

I want to retrieve files that were deleted from my network folders from Amazon Glacier via Cloudberry. I do not have an exact number for the files that were deleted and was wondering if it is possible to figure that out through Cloudberry.

Answer (score 0):

I work at CloudBerry. Please specify:

1. Files deleted from network folders, but they still exist on Glacier or both?
2. Are files deleted from CloudBerry Backup storage tab?
3. Do you back up straight to Glacier or via a lifecycle policy S3-Glacier?

Comment: 1. They exist on the Glacier but not on network folder. 2. They are not deleted from Cloudberry backup storage tab. 3. Straight backup to Glacier.